# Why would someone reject this edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21080896) ended up being approved, but one of the reviewers rejected it as:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service,
>   or is deliberately destructive.

Was this just a troll? All I did was take OP screenshot of their code and transcribe it into a code block. I fail to see how anyone could reject it on that ground.

Comment: One can only guess.. I suppose it is easy to overlook the code link at the top of the post and mistake it for adding additional stuff.. I wouldnt worry about it. It's why an edit needs to be approved by multiple reviewers

Comment: if that's the case, then maybe this isn't an appropriate meta post. I was just seeking clarity. I haven't edited many posts, so I just wanted to make sure I hadn't done anything wrong.

Comment: IMO providing the code should be the responsibility of OP, not transcribed into the post by another user. There's too much risk of a manual mistake creeping in by transcribing rather than copy-pasting. I'd have voted to reject as well, though using a custom reason rather than defacement.

Comment: I would probably have rejected such an edit. Does that mean I'm a troll?

Comment: In the second line you changed `'` to `"` and removed a space - at that point I'd probably have stop checking and rejected the edit (assuming I bothered to do a line-by-line comparison at all). I guess that specific difference wouldn't change anything in the execution, but at the very least it's clear that you're not transcribing it exactly, thus there may be other errors.

Comment: @TinyGiant I didn't think the fact that it was rejected was trolling. I thought the reason attached didn't make any sense and that the person was just rejecting edits for no reason.

Comment: You assumed that because you didn't understand the reason there must be no reason, and jumped immediately to calling someone a troll. Don't you think there should be something between _"I don't understand"_ and _"TROLL!!!"_? Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @TinyGiant then maybe I still don't understand the reason. Can you please elaborate on how this is either A) promotes a service or product or B) is deliberately destructive. After reading the answers below, I understand why this type of edit would be rejected, but that reason still does not fit.

Comment: The label for that reason in the edit review queue is "spam or vandalism". I could see how someone would use that in a situation like this for a variety of reasons. It may not be the correct reason to use, but I can see how someone might have gotten there.

Comment: @TinyGiant I know I probably should just stay out of this, but I have a strong opinion. I believe that user-moderators always have a responsibility of clear communication to users they are moderating, and in this case the rejection reason was not so clearly communicated. Everyone who is ingrained enough in this community to be reading this meta post effectively has a leadership role at SO, and along with that comes the responsibility of clearly communicating to the newer users why we take the actions that we do. In this case the communication failure was very small, but a failure nonetheless.

Comment: @Maximillian of course. As I said it may not have been the correct reason to choose, and it is everyone's responsibility to be as clear as possible. I'm taking issue with the jumping straight from _"I don't understand"_ to _"that person must be a troll"_.

Comment: If you don't understand something, you should attempt to expand your understanding. If you don't understand why a program you've written is behaving in a given way, do you assume that it is trolling you? Furthermore if you performed an action that you mistakenly thought to be correct then found a meta discussion where someone called you a troll because that person didn't understand your reasoning, how would that make you feel?

Comment: I respectfully disagree with @MichaelDodd’s opinion that editors shouldn’t touch code. I do agree that authors should have placed code in there in the first place, but they didn’t. If there is an error in the edit, the author (or another editor) can update that. But I feel more accessible code is a much higher priority than the chance of coercion. In fact, I often turn code blocks into snippets to make it easier to “copy from snippet” for answerers. Not once have I introduced a bug as a result.

Comment: *I feel more accessible code is a much higher priority...* I don't generally transcribe images myself but I've had to in the review queue because users insist on inserting images of error messages into questions for new users. Rejecting doesn't work: even if the next reviewer rejects it (and they usually don't) someone else will just suggest the same edit again and *that* gets approved.

Comment: @vol7ron There's a big difference between copy-pasting code into a snippet or indenting it (which is generally really hard to mess up and not a lot of work for either editor or reviewer) and manually rewriting it from an image.

Comment: @vol7ron I'm not saying "don't touch code at all", I regularly make edits to posts where code is not indented correctly or isn't using the correct markup, and your example of turning code blocks into snippets is also an example of a good edit. I'm just saying that it's not a good idea to transcribe someone else's **image of code** into text as it carries an inherent risk of introducing new mistakes (as per Dukeling's first comment). In that case, OP should fix their own post by copy-pasting their code into the question.

Comment: Good to know. Though, I made two points, which the first seems to be overlooked. Accessibility. It is an overloaded term and many of its inferences apply. — 1) First and foremost, it’s not available to unsighted or sight-challenged individuals. The site may never be fully conducive to those individuals, but we should make an effort to support where we can. — 2) Foreign-hosted images are less trustworthy, harder to read, disconnected from the post, and require more work to obtain information, making it less accessible to visually see as well as interact with (copy/paste)

Comment: While I agree that an author of a post should be discouraged from taking screenshots of error messages and code (and should transcribe it themselves), I don’t think editors should be discouraged from doing the transcription. Two wrongs don’t make a right. That isn’t to say I am firm to this idea — if there are observations where transcriptions are frequently misleading or riddled with errors, at that point we should pull back from encouraging transcriptions, but we shouldn’t arrive at those conclusions based on hypothetical speculation.

Comment: @vol7ron if there is an error introduced by the editor then it is absolutely not more accessible. It is actually less accessible because anyone reading the question is going to assume the author posted the code as is, and won't bother to go to the revision history to find the link to the image of the code. It is just a bad idea. If the OP wants to transcribe their own code then that is on them.

Comment: I don’t agree it’s less accessible. If you’re using a screen reader all you know is there’s an image with no context to the content or subject matter. Even an error-added transcription is better than nothing. If you need an example seek YouTube closed captions which are not 100% correct and something is better than nothing. I also think it’s speculative to suggest that people will be introducing errors. That’s trying to solve a problem that doesn’t exist. If it’s an issue, address it in the future, but I think it’s a bit naive to assume it will be an issue just because the potential exists.

Comment: @vol7ron my argument stands. If there is an error in the code introduced by the editor, people reading the question will assume that the OP made the error and that that error is the cause of the problem. This would actually prevent the author from getting any help. Even if that doesn't happen, answerers will still be confused and won't be able to see how the OP could get the error they are saying they got when the code "they" provided does not produce that error. The question will then be closed as "not reproducible", "unclear what you're asking", or "Debugging / no MCVE".

Comment: Your argument still makes unfounded assumptions and the whole time the image doesn’t carry over, a blind individual or even someone with color blindness may be struggling with that image. The good outweighs the chance of the bad, which would naturally correct itself in some way that would prompt the author to review the edit. — I have faith in the editors here that the overwhelming majority are not that error prone for those that are actually willing to make the effort to convert an image to text

Comment: @vol7ron something that makes no sense is not better than the lack of something that makes sense. It is confusing and detrimental at best. It helps no one ever. Sorry but I don't know how else to say it. It's like saying putting sugar in your gas tank is good because it's better than nothing. It's not, and it will be worse than if you didn't.

Comment: See the answer below that details the numerous errors introduced to the code then tell me that all of those errors and a code block which makes no sense at all and replaces the image entirely is a good thing. It isn't and no amount of spin or hand waving about screen readers is going to make a code block that doesn't make any sense make sense.

Comment: Yes it seems those are a number of issues. I don’t discount that human error is a risk. However, view a site without your eyes and see how much more helpful a little bit of information can be, even if it’s to tell you it’s not something you’re interested in. You’re arguing about correctness, which even if a transcription contains numerous errors it is more accessible if a screen reader can read the content. Also note that for the one bad example listed, I could give 10 good examples. My point still stands, unless it’s a meaningful issue, accessibility is more important.

Comment: @vol7ron no, a little bit of nonsense is not better than nothing. If it only serves to confuse then nothing would be better. I feel like I'm repeating myself here to no end. Bad information  is not better than no information and it can only serve to make the problem worse, not better. Accessibility _is_ important, and that means not introducing irrelevant, faulty, and confusing information to the question that serves only to prevent the author and all readers from achieving any semblance of a positive outcome. Such a distraction serves only to hinder the question and accessibility.

Comment: The best possible outcome from editing faulty or confusing information into a question is that the time of everyone who reads the question is wasted. Plain and simple. No ifs, ands, or buts about it.

Comment: @TinyGiant I feel you’re arguing and not even trying to see it from another perspective. You are repeating yourself. I’m sure you come across countless questions and are able to visually see that it isn’t a question you are interested in just by a quick glance at the code. Spelling and syntax errors don’t even affect you at that decision point. Someone that’s blind comes to the page, is interested in the question, finds it goes to an external URL, follows it, finds instead of it being a code fiddle, it’s an image and has reached a dead end.

Comment: You’re making a case because of one example? Try looking up the countless positive cases where code has been edited and refactored.

Comment: @vol7ron This question is about this specific example. _"Why would someone reject this edit?"_. You have yet to provide a convincing argument that a faulty transcription with numerous errors that drastically change the operation of the code along with the removal of the existing reference to the actual code that does not contain those errors can possibly be a good thing. The reason that someone would reject this edit is that it is a patently bad edit that does nothing to improve the quality or clarity of the post, and does in-fact reduce the quality and clarity of the post.

Comment: _"Someone that’s blind comes to the page, is interested in the question, finds it goes to an external URL, follows it, finds instead of it being a code fiddle, it’s an image and has reached a dead end."_ The alternative you're advocating for is: Is interested in question, finds an irrelevant and erroneously transcribed code sample presented as the author's code that does not demonstrate the problem described in the question, they waste a bunch of time trying to make sense of the question to no avail, and best case they leave confused. That's not better, it's just wasteful.

Comment: Again you’re trying to address a problem that doesn’t exist or is infrequently encountered. As stated above, if that occurs more frequently than expected, it should be addressed — I think we’re in agreement there. One of the solutions may be what you’re advocating here. But an infrequent scenario of something involving limited impact should not be the issue that sets the standard.

Comment: The conversation in this chain isn’t about a specific scenario. It’s in a relation to a comment that someone made saying editors shouldn’t touch the code in the OP — I’ll leave out names. It’s general and I can’t judge your motives but I think it’s a bit of deflection to circle back to that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Comment: This should probably also be marked as duplicate of [Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Thanks for putting in the effort to transcribe that image into text which can be copied elsewhere.  That was pretty cool of you to do.

Most reviewers, however, would close the question *instead* of transcribing images, since there's a lot of risk involved in doing that transcription; notably, copy errors or your transcription introducing *new* problems.

I think it was good of you to take the effort, but the real responsibility is on the original author of the question. It is their question; edits are only for making sure it looks nice and neat. It is not our responsibility to transcribe everything, and it is often best to simply close the question until the author could edit it themselves. (Questions that lack a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-exmaple) within the text of the question itself can be closed as "a community-specific reason → needs debugging details".)

But thanks nonetheless.

Comment: ...or, occasionally, your transcription *fixing* errors unintentionally. ;-)

Answer (score 41):

Besides the general "don't transcribe image code into text" (with which you can agree or not), this specific example introduces a large number of new bugs and is more or less useless. Every reviewer who accepted this made a bad job. If anyone would be going to answer the question based on the transcribed code, they would state a large number of errors that simply weren't there in the image:

- Line 2: Replaced " with ', removed whitespace at end of string.
- Line 4: Changed `ETAGM11` to `ETAGM`
- Line 6: Added whitespace
- Line 7: Changed `INP1` to `IMP1`
- Line 25: Changed `input1.i = input2.j` to `input1.i = input2.i`
- Line 32: Changed `oldinput.i` to `oldinput.1`
- Line 42: `DAYA` instead of `DATA`

Some of them might not be that important, but the majority drastically changes the program.

Comment: Which makes this suggested edit a good example of one of the reasons that the consensus is we don't transcribe code into questions for OPs.

Answer (score 16):

Only the person who rejected can tell you why they did so.

But I'm not sure I'd accept a *"code-transcription"* edit either. Most likely I'd skip, but it is something that I believe the original author should do, and most importantly transcription could introduce new/different errors that would render the question moot.

Your intentions are good, and your edit was approved in the end, but I have to question how a user who's not prepared to actually copy/paste their own code is going to be ready to support their question so it gets a useful answer anyway.

Until they do, the better move is to close the question so the user can work on it. Providing a working example is *their* responsability.

As such, an edit like this could be seen by some as a waste of time for other reviewers, since you are asking other users to put a **lot** of effort to validate your edit (they would have to compare your edit to the screenshot line by line to see it is actually good), for a question that would very likely not be up to scratch if its original user is not willing to do the minimum effort to provide a better quality post.

And the user how voted to reject must certainly was not *"a troll"*. Assuming that someone who votes or act in a way you disagree could be described as such is not a great move.

Comment: I would go so far as saying that calling a user a "troll" is "unkind or unwelcoming"...

Comment: To be fair, I didn't think it being rejected was a troll, but the reason for rejection is what made me think they were trolling.

Comment: @SaggingRufus People who are trolling are called trolls, so you just called that reviewer a troll.

Comment: @Mark They didn't. The use of the work might have not been the best idea, but they just came over to meta to make a question. No need to focus on that so much, IMO. I just mentioned in the end because I thought it could be useful, but it's not like Rufus went around lobbing personal accusations.

Comment: It could be as simple as that the reviewer just accidentally picked the wrong close reason.