# An edit that replaces an screenshot of code with actual code: how to handle?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits, specific-edit

Just came across this 'suggested edit' review task: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23329610

[image: screenshot]

The review comment is: "CODE FORMATTING".

What is the most appropriate way to handle this?

I suspect that even carefully reviewing the typed-in code to make sure it reproduces that from the screenshot may be prone to error.

Comment: Well, it *is* a review so unless you're willing to spend the time to verify that it's correct I'd suggest skipping. If the code matches that in the image it's a clear improvement.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375127/why-would-someone-reject-this-edit

Comment: @yivi: The link doesn't answer how such edits should be reviewed.

Comment: @BDL I interpret those answers as _"rejecting this edit is fine, since posting the actual code is the OP responsibility. skipping is also fine. you can approve, but it's up to you making the due diligence to make sure the transcription is OK"_.

Comment: Funnily enough, the edit was approved. And the OP [came back with a new screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56697353/revisions). Which further reinforces the point about "better reject and close and let the OP understand what's wrong with their question". Also, even with the transcribed code I'm not sure the question is out of "closable" territory.

Comment: I can’t understand in the first place, why did the editor took time to read the image and paste the code? They should just close the question if the op is not providing any code but the image of code. People will not go on writing code from images of every user and this user is not special

Comment: A lot of people on this site spend time doing what the OP could have done in the first place, I don't really see how this is much different.

Comment: Screenshot for error code is totally fine but in this case OP post screenshots of code which could be easily made into snippet either by built-in snippet provided or external sources. Which lack of effort and respect to others. Good edit nevertheless but OP kind of rollback the edit to the original version somehow.

Comment: @weegee Is it so hard to believe that people do things just because they're trying to be (too) nice?

Comment: @Gimby NO. They are not being nice, they are making the OP irresponsible. If they want to be nice then they should politely guide the user to how to post a question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did review the transcription, character by character and it does seem to match.

However, I feel inclined to reject this edit for these reasons:

1. it is the responsibility of OP to provide an adequate [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
2. editing sends the wrong message to OP (and others) that it is acceptable to provide an inadequate one (in the form of a screenshot) instead
3. such edits take excessive, valuable time from reviewers, that could be more productively used for less drastic edits, **on top of** being prone to errors.

Comment: While I agree with all your points. _such edits take excessive, valuable time from reviewers_ then we can do them a favour and approve the edit instead of rejecting it but also tell them that closing is more relevant than editing in this case