# What’s would have been the correct choice for this "Suggested Edit"?

Tags: support, review-suspension

Here is a link to the *single* review that I recently approved that has led to me being suspended from the Review Queues:

[Review 31768292](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31768292).

In summary the aforementioned *"Suggested Edit"* replaces a pixel based image of tabular data with the equivalent table recreated using the [GitHub-flavored markdown format](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-).

IMO, a text based table is preferable over an image based one for Assistive Technology (AT) reasons (plus [other reasons too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question))... hence why I accepted it.

After re-reviewing the post my assumption for being suspended is because I also didn’t edit the opening sentence of the OP that reads as follows:

> *I have a network's data in tabular form (like in the screenshot)*

Presumably, the *”like in the screenshot”* part should have been revised too, e.g, changed to *”like in the table shown below”*

Please can anyone confirm if there are other issues with the  *"Suggested Edit"* that I’ve missed or misunderstood as I’d like like to mitigate against any future suspension?

Comment: To avoid suspension from Review Queues there are so many land mines to be mindful of. One misjudgement and you’re suspended.

Comment: But if you didn't get suspended then you wouldn't know that you made a misjudgement?

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine - yes, that’s one way to find out. It would be better if the _dos and don'ts_ of what _is/isn’t_ acceptable in Review Queues was documented somewhere - then informed judgements could be made.

Comment: Re *"...a text based table is preferable over an image based one"*: Not only that— *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* - for example (my emphasis), *"Images should* ***only*** *be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*)

Comment: The canonical for *this question* may be *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen - agreed. However, apparently (as per the accepted answer in the [duplicate post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040/should-we-edit-a-question-to-transcribe-code-from-an-image-to-text)) replacing a table image with a Markdown table may _“... introduce errors”_,  and _“Might not replicate original code”_. (Neither applicable to Review 31768292). It’s getting so difficult to make informed judgements when reviewing because of such conflicting/lack-of guidelines. What rules apply has become a guessing game.

Comment: @Robc you can read *"Might not replicate original code"*  as "Might not replicate original text"; the fact that I say "code" isn't a good reason to ignore the advice. It's like when people state that the conanical duplicate [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) isn't applicable to the picture you transcribed because it doesn't say "data". The couple of bullet points isn't an exhaustive list; it's just 2 example reasons.

Comment: @Larnu - Thanks and just to clarify I’m not ignoring the advice. At the time of approving the suggested edit I didn’t know the advice, tucked away in a meta post, existed.