# Rejected review for converting image into textual table

Tags: discussion, review-queues, moderation

As a reviewer, I came across a suggested review for which another reviewer and I decided to accept, but that a moderator decided to reject.

Specifically, the original post contained an embedded image of a table and the suggested review converted the image of the table into text, in order to make it easier for devs to troubleshoot the problem through copy-paste of the table.

Given that the content of the textual table was the same of the one of the image table, and given that having a textual table is definitely better (I think) than having an image representing a table, are there some reasons for which it was rejected?

You can find the link of the review [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31768292).

Comment: Apparently it's exactly the same user that accepted the answer with me on the same review, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was a pretty safe duplicate :)

Comment: See also *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040/)*.

Comment: Yes Peter, I was just reading it as the duplicate reference to the Robc post. I've been suspended too, although I thought to be reviewing with attention and purpose. Is there a reference guide of golden rules for reviewing on SO? Or maybe some faqs to address most of the cases. @NickstandswithUkraine

Comment: @lemon Nope, just live and learn (unless you want to spend days on meta), accept mistakes and don't be disheartened. Accepting mistakes can also lead to moderators (if they notice that you've accepted and understood the mistake) reducing/removing review suspensions as well.

Comment: Kind of, @lemon. For reviewing suggested edits, the guidance is usually inferred from the [editing guidelines FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/11407695). Unfortunately, the guideline for not transcribing images is not there (I'll try to address that shortcoming). Honestly, I think we should revisit the guidance to add a caveat for cases like yours and RobC's because it's pretty obvious that the edit did not introduce any mistakes, but the guidance's still a guidance, and changing it requires a Meta discussion and forming a consensus first.

Comment: Since review suspensions aren't a punishment (in most cases, but you have to be particularly inept to earn a "permanent" one), and since you acknowledge the problem, you can safely ask for the suspension to be lifted (unless there is a pattern of other reviews that lead to the mod deciding you need a break).

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions @OlegValteriswithUkraine, I'll go through the guidelines FAQ. In the end, the objective is doing what's best for the community instead of what's best for me, or in general, for a specific user.

Comment: @lemon NP - I added the guideline to the FAQ so as it is obvious without knowing about the Q&A linked by Peter. Just as a small FYI, you can always drop by [BSOR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews) chat room if you need guidance, unsure, or just want to discuss a particular review or overall guidance.