# Why is block / code format "text" still interpreted in display?

Tags: support, markdown

In a [recent answer I made](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73799525/1818059) I put the result of a table and an SQLite query. I put the code block as "text", including backtics etc. Trying to make formatting concise and correct. It is separated from the SQL block above.

But the text part is still rendered with color formatting, trying to interpret the dates etc. While still readable, did I miss something to make the formatting be just text ? It's confusing to see some part formatting. Example, "Sep" is black, but "Dec" is red, probably because it's interpreted as "Decimal".

Comment: `\`\`\`text` is not a valid language hint. See the list: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108) `none` or `lang-none` or `lang-text` or `lang-plaintext` or  `lang-txt` are valid

Comment: Someone edited the post. I should have checked and found that "text" is not plaintext.  Thanks to VLAZ for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat this was already linked in comment #1. But YES, my question is answered, and my original answer on SO was edited (for me). So the original question is no longer applicable.

Comment: The system itself ought to be more helpful. The missing help is a (bad) excuse to [use images instead of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040). Even simple heuristics could cover more than 90% of the cases (without too many false positives).

Comment: ([The MSE version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) is more direct: *"If you don't want to have any syntax highlighting, you can use the lang-none language code"*)