# Should I edit questions to "tidy" code snippets?

Tags: discussion, edits, tidy

I often see questions or answers with code snippets that have weird code styles or odd indentations. The snippet popup has a button to auto-tidy the code, but it seems not many people notice it or care to use it.

So my question is: is it worth it to edit the question/answer only to press the tidy button? It makes the code look a lot better, but I'm not sure if it counts as a ["tiny, trivial edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: You have full edit privileges (hence no review, the "too minor" rule applies mostly to suggested edits) - feel free to make as many small edits as you like (just don't batxh such edits too much)

Comment: While you are at it, fix everything else in the post that can be fixed (to the best of your ability). An ***exception*** would be [transcribing code, error messages, or command line sessions from image to text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040). If they are that careless there is probably a lot more to do.

Comment: If you are specifically referring to Stack snippets and its "tidy" button I suggest using a bit of caution/discretion when using it as depending on code language and library specifics it can have some drastic effects on the resultant "cleaned up" code. In other words, make sure the tidying action doesn't actually break the code. As a rule of thumb I generally only edit code snippets to address whitespace issues as a way to improve readability. It's my opinion that all other code sample aspects are perfectly reviewable for syntax issues/typos/etc and should ***not*** be edited.