# Review the following question to consider reopening it

Tags: support, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

The following question: [Calculating partial months salary costings for employees on a project in excel [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74267399/calculating-partial-months-salary-costings-for-employees-on-a-project-in-excel) was closed 3 days ago since then I made significant changes to the question (I am familiar with the question because I posted an accepted answer to a similar one: [sequence a sumif with exclusions in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74253310/sequence-a-sumif-with-exclusions-in-excel)). I suspect the issue is a long queue for reopening questions, so it takes considerable time to get it reviewed and possibly reopened.

Actually, I have a possible solution for the closed question, that I would like to post once it gets reopened. The reason for this question here in Meta Stack Overflow is to bring attention to this question, so it can be reviewed. Maybe it is a general issue that takes significant time once the edit was submitted.

Comment: The question is in the reopen queue; patience my young padawan. (This is why ensuring your question is in a good condition when you first post it is so important, as then you don't have to wait for it to be reopened.)

Comment: Edits to questions are usually not meant to drastically modify the question. You, for example. [shouldn't transcribe images to text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040/should-we-edit-a-question-to-transcribe-code-from-an-image-to-text). You definitely shouldn't remove the code that op already tried, because now it looks like a zero-effort do-my-work-for-me question. I'm very inclined to roll-back the edits because they make too drastic changes to the content (where noone expect the op know if they are even correct)

Comment: Not to forget that your transcriptions aren't correct. Example: End date of Bob was `06/05/2020`, but in your version is `5/3/2021`. Dave: changed from `30/05/2020` to `5/30/2020`. (which also means that you swapped order of day and month). Second table: Original salaries were given in £, but your data contains $. Salary values are also changed. Bob daily salary was 199, but is now 217.

Comment: @BDL thanks for your feedback, I will review it, the formula is not there but the link where the formula was provided is there (my answer to the other question). I was in contact with the OP via SO chat from the previous question, so we discussed this second question. I will check the typos you mentioned.

Comment: The question has now been reopened!

Comment: I see your point now @BDL yes I modified Bob's information to have richer sample data, where a resource is not assigned to any project even though he was already hired. The initial input data didn't have this case, which is why I modified the sample to include it. To avoid any questions about this particular scenario in the comments. I did it still under the original question intention, but just let me know, I can put exactly the sample data and the currency that was used in the previous version of the question.

Comment: “but the link where the formula was provided is there” - Which is the reason your edit should have been rejected. All information necessary to answer the question should be in the question body not in an external link. Which is probably the reason the question was closed.

Comment: @SecurityHound then I will add it, even I don't think it can be used to resolve the problem on this question, but I will add it.

Comment: *"The question has now been reopened"* I must admit, the fact that people posting on meta works to get content "sped" through the queue is a mockery of the queues...

Comment: (*[Use of commas before "that"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/)*. [Example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/188750/is-there-a-rule-to-rather-use-points-and-not-commas-as-decimal-separators-in-aca/188756#188756))

Comment: @TheThonnu: Great, but why? The question is still lacking focus. Did you vote to re-open just because he asked, or for a different reason?

Comment: @Cerbrus - I thought it was focused enough to be reopened, and two others agreed with me.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think now the question has more focus than the previous version. Actually, at least there is one answer posted, so it means at least one person understood it. On top of it, one member who voted to close the question now voted to reopen it. Anyway, it is a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: Being the author of that answer, you're a little biased, @DavidLeal... Not exactly impartial. "More focused" is not necessarily "Focused". It's still a massive wall of text that should be simplified, especially considering the even larger wall of text that answer is...

Comment: @Cerbrus it is a complex problem to solve in Excel, which is why it requires some explanation, but this section is *optional*, for people who want to understand the rationale behind it, better to over-communicate than under-communicate. this is how I see it. In the same way, better to have a question with a large answer than nothing. As I said it is a matter of personal preferences.  Thanks for your feedback, I will try to be more concise next time. We are all providing opinions (not facts), we are not free from being biased

Comment: It is curious the question was closed again, *"This question needs to be more focused"* with no comments on the type of focus it is needed now. Instead of trying to improve it, better to vote to close it again. At least I was able to improve the original question and provide an answer. Now it is the time for others (including the OP) to improve it in a way it has the expected focus, and hopefully additional answers. Thanks to the people who voted to reopen it, so I could publish my answer.

Comment: Posting to meta doesn't magically prove some measure of... clarity/focus/usefulness, etc

Comment: Problems on SO should be boiled down to what the actual problem you're looking to solve is. They shouldn't be the equivalent of reading comprehension problems. The fact that you're handling people data, and salaries, partial allocations, none of that is actually the root of the problem you're solving, it makes sense to you, being the one with the problem to be solved, but if you broke things down a step further to just plain old columns/rows, your problem becomes applicable to a far wider audience.

Comment: The fact that solving the problem requires a few dozen different steps plays into the idea that this problem needs more focus

Comment: Sorry @KevinB providing a large answer that requires several steps doesn't prove anything about the lack of focus of the question. A good example of that is [Fermat Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiles%27s_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem), well defined in a single line and the proof took more than 129 pages. If Wiles had published his solution on SO it would be down voted, following our rationale, :-)

Comment: Yes, that would in fact be content not meant for SO. We also don't allow cooking recipes, legal briefs, or astronomy here.

Comment: IMO Excel falls into that category of questions which are allowed in begrudgingly because yeah okay there is some form of relationship with programming. But it's not really programming, so good luck writing a question which pass the test that questions about actual programming problems get subjected to. You can scroll a little through the pages of questions. I see more zero score and downvoted than actual upvoted questions. Long story short... maybe Stack Overflow is not the right castle for this type of question, even if on paper it passes the rules.

Comment: @Gimby another specific with Excel is that Microsoft added a significant number of [new functions](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates.htm) for array operations and iteration among data elements, which makes the formulas not as simple as it was before. Now you can have in a single formula like a subroutine with variables defined, array operations, iterating over all elements, etc. In summary, the scope of Excel has changed significantly, and now with a single formula, you can do calculations that you required VBA before, but the formula is larger obviously.

Answer (score -3):

A week after I posted my question in META Stackoverflow, let me summarize what happened until then:

The question was reopened and I was able to post my answer. One hour later the question was closed again for the following reason: "The question needs more [focused](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)".

According to the previous link here is the definition of this cause:

> **Needs more focus** - If your question has *many valid answers* (but no way to determine which, if any, are correct), then it probably
> needs to be more focused to be successful in our format.
>
> This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should
> focus on one problem only.
>
> This can often be fixed by breaking the post into multiple questions,
> or by focusing on a specific part of the problem.

Basically, there are two root cause scenarios:

1. Question has many valid answers
2. Multiple questions in one

The first one doesn't apply because based on the description of the question and the input data, there is **only one possible output**, i.e. the question is not ambiguous.

The second one, the question is very specific in the ask. The ask in the question can be **summarized** as follow: *Find the time interval interceptions of the two input tables to calculate the monthly cost*. It is true in the context of the financial sample, with simple data (a maximum of six columns on each input table and no more than `18` rows). You can mock data, but the problem remains the same. Is it really necessary for this case?

I tried to improve the original question, **knowing upfront the problem**, because I posted an answer from the same OP for a similar, but more specific scenario (not considering the monthly partial allocation of the resources). I also interacted with the OP through chat, where I suggested posting another question to solve a more generic case. The original question was posted under the UK locale and with data that doesn't capture all the scenarios.

I edit the question with my US locale (using `$` currency and dates in `MM/DD/YYYY`). Even though I didn't change the original intent of the question, based on the comments received I should have submitted the edit with the same locale and kept the same input data, then in my answer to use more data to consider additional scenarios with my own locale.

Here is the summary of the *"casualties"* of my META question:

- 24 negative votes for my META question (I understand the meaning of a negative vote in META). The original intention of my question was to find out if the cause of not being reviewed yet is due to a long queue or if the review was unattended. Now I understand the review process can take longer.
- 9 negatives votes for the edited question in SO
- The question was closed again
- 3 negatives votes to the answer I posted and two positives.
- **The answer was accepted by the OP**
- One comment (after the question was reopened) suggested to use of a more specific product such as [SmartSheet](https://www.smartsheet.com/), which is a valid suggestion, but it is not a free product, nor an excel free plug-in.
- Not a single comment or hint on why this question is considered with a lack of focus
- Not a single comment or tip on why the answer was downvoted

Here are some other questions (not closed) related to Resource Management:

- [Number of days of current week within a given date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329352/number-of-days-of-current-week-within-a-given-date-range)
- [Create a table in a new sheet with data from two different tables in two different sheets in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499533/create-a-table-in-a-new-sheet-with-data-from-two-different-tables-in-two-differe). Has this question more focus? Is it better explained?
- [Distributing the hours from master table to all the matching values in reference table using excel formula or power queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280513/distributing-the-hours-from-master-table-to-all-the-matching-values-in-reference). This could be solved using a Resource Management tool, right?
- [Returning list of projects that are assigned to a person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647661/returning-list-of-projects-that-are-assigned-to-a-person). Another resource management question

The truth is that people use Excel for basic resource management stuff and therefore it is expected to have questions related to this problem.

@Gimby, pointed out in the comments an interesting observation:

> IMO Excel falls into that category of questions which are allowed in
> begrudgingly because yeah okay there is some form of relationship with
> programming. But it's not really programming, so good luck writing a
> question which pass the test that questions about actual programming
> problems get subjected to. You can scroll a little through the pages
> of questions. I see more zero score and downvoted than actual upvoted
> questions. Long story short... maybe Stack Overflow is not the right
> castle for this type of question, even if on paper it passes the
> rules.

So some Excel questions, even on paper pass all the rules, but people's perception is that it is not the case.

Now I understand better how to edit a question, and that is normal for a review process to take more than three days, but above all what I learned is that **sometimes** what Wikipedia says about [Stackoverflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) is true:

> The site's culture has been criticized for being unfriendly...

None of the above *"casualties"* contributed to helping the OP to solve the problem or to improve the question, not a second answer was provided with a better solution under Excel that may be justified my answer was downvoted. No additional edits were submitted to improve further the question.

I understand people don't have to explain their votes/actions but certainly helps to understand how a question or an answer can be improved and in the end, it promotes better collaboration.

Comment: Yet another meta post jumping to "unfriendly" not justified by the evidence given.

Comment: I think it's less SO being unfriendly and more the question is long with a huge dump of data. I'd trim the data to just Bob in both tables, add a value for "Daily Salary" instead of the formula, then ask your "I am looking for an Excel ...  just return a 1x12 array. **This would reduced the time required to understand and increase the chance someone answers or upvote.** Also this is very specialized, maybe a more generic title.

Comment: @JamesRisner thanks that would explain the downvotes of the question, but not the downvotes to the answer I provided.

Comment: @DavidLeal I just looked at your answer. It looks fine, but oh my is it long.

Comment: Thanks, @JamesRisner I wish I could find a shorter one, I was expecting other contributions to finding a shorter way, but unfortunately, the question was closed to find out. The formula is large, mainly defining names, and `SPLIT` function (it can be defined in the *Name Manager*), but the logic is very short. I added an Explanation section because it uses a set of new Excel functions that people are not familiar with. Thanks for your feedback.