# Should editors edit questions to add code from provided links?

Tags: discussion

My gut stance is that an editor should not edit a question to include the source that is referenced by a link in the question, as that changes the question.  I typically want to encourage posters to follow the site guidelines themselves and have them update the questions, themselves, to include the source code when appropriate.

But in trying to find a community resource related to this, I found the general [Edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) page which has:

> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> ```
> to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> **to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it**
> to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> to add related resources or hyperlinks
> ```

My initial reaction is that changing the question to include the linked to source changes the post, but then again in that case all you are really doing is making it so that other users don't have to go to an offline resource to get the info. And not encouraging the OP to do it themselves.

So I guess I'm looking for community feedback on this.

Comment: I sometimes roll others edits back if they do that.

Comment: I see a bunch of links of people saying "Yes" (including some CMs) but I remember other questions where the top answer was "No" due to license concerns

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeah, that's the one I linked :p, namely: *"However, it is still a bad idea for people to do this. And it is unnecessary. If the OP doesn't copy his code into his Question when prompted to, there is a straightforward remedy: vote to close the Question, and move on."*

Comment: A bit of a side-effect of fixing it for OP is that they don't properly learn. If they have to add code themselves, they know and learn it's required to add it directly. (Exceptions exist of course, but there's always people who don't care)

Comment: I guess my take away so far is, "You can but don't be angry if another editor rolls it back"? Heh.

Comment: The even worse thing I've seen is, that some people take the code from an image the OP posted and edit into the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, [canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375127/why-would-someone-reject-this-edit) for that too

Comment: And indeed canonical [When should I make edits to code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) says: "**Don't**... Copy code from a linked site into the question"

Comment: Another issue is that you could, with all the good intention in the world, still introduce unrelated errors into the code you bring over, causing more harm than good.

Comment: There is another issue in that you have no way of knowing whether the code that *currently* resides at the URI is the code the OP is talking about, i.e. the whole reason why we require that all information is in the question in the first place. Links change, links die.