# Edit to replace images with Markdown tables was rejected

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

My suggested edit to an answer, replacing an image of table containing code with a Markdown table representation of the same content [was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27817859).

Why?

Comment: I’m not in a position find it right now but there is a meta post where the consensus is not to transcribe images. I can’t recall if that was specific to code or not but that might have been why.

Comment: On the review page, if you switch between "Rendered output" and "Markdown" several times, you'll see that the table disappears in the Rendered output, which might be the reason why.

Comment: @L.F. That’s a bug reported here: [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357464/289905).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was not one of the people who rejected your edit, however I would have rejected it as you made the answer incorrect. If you look at the last line of the table in the image, both the "Verbatim literal" and "Resulting string" columns have two lines in them (reflecting the `\r\n` in the "Regular literal"). The table that you edited in does not have those line breaks. I have subsequently edited the answer to correct that.

Comment: Thanks, I have noted this mistake. Accepted this answer instead.

Comment: this should be done as an improvement to the suggested edit or even "reject and edit" rather than just flatly rejecting it and leaving the problem images as the reviewers here have done

Answer (score 6):

I believe it was incorrectly rejected.

Can't say why the reviewers chose to reject it, maybe they were not familiar with the newly implemented table syntax, or maybe they didn't like how the markdown rendered. It's hard to guess *why* other users do anything if they do not explain in themselves, and guessing is rarely useful.

The only thing we can say is that they believed your edit didn't improve the post, and it's an opinion that I disagree with.

But in any case, replacing an image of text/code with the actual text represented by the image is a good edit for an answer in my book. The use of tables is purely circumstantial, even without the table syntax replacing that image with a textual representation of the content would have been a good edit in my book.

Comment: It's better for people using screen readers.

Comment: And for anyone wanting to copy and paste. Or that wants the "light/dark" scheme apply to the whole post, including the table. Etc. Etc. Etc. Text as an image is very rarely a good idea.

Comment: Here's the canonical: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged/320060#320060)

Comment: @SuperJade The canonical is actually [here, in the MSO FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: *I believe it was incorrectly rejected.* That's wrong. Transcribing images is in general a problematic topic, but **wrong** transcriptions definitely have to be rejected.

Comment: Interestingly, this is the opposite of the advice given in [your answer to the question pointed out by @SuperJade](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375128/215552)...

Comment: @Heretic In that case, it was a question. In this one, it's an answer. I point out that the edit is a good one **for an answer**.