# How do I add CSS libraries to my Stack Snippet?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

When I asked the question I wanted to include a Stack Snippet, but the images, fonts and the [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) grid were giving me issues, so I'm asking if there is a way that could be fixed.

This is what I'm talking about:
[image]

Normally, there is supposed to be a font awesome icon before the text "Company Name"\

This is the link to my question: [I want to make a form validation that will not be hindered by any other element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253143/i-want-to-make-a-form-validation-that-will-not-be-hindered-by-any-other-element)

Comment: This question lacks a lot of details, or maybe even all details needed to do something with it.

Comment: also - stack overflow has its own meta - I'd migrate it, but I suspect it would get closed for the same reason there

Comment: _"If you are having a problem which you want to quickly solve"_ then you don't head down to Stack Overflow to **post a new question**.  If you wanted it solved quickly it's likely the wrong type of question for SO because either you won't get a quick answer, or because if you get a quick answer it's most likely a common question with a trillion duplicates, and a bit more research was warranted in the first place.

Comment: You need to use absolute paths to resources, not relative paths that don't exist on the stack snippets server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went ahead and made the following edits to your question:

- Moved the code into a runnable snippet
- Added external libraries
- Replaced "enter image description" text with image descriptions
- Replaced screenshot of text with text
- Removed "please help" text
- I also made the background black because the text in your code was white

Some tips and suggestions:

- There is a [FAQ for how to add Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) if you need further help.
- Well maintained tags will have links to where libraries/APIs/etc. are hosted. If you're looking for downloads, documentation, libraries, tutorials, etc. check the tag info first. For example, the [bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4) tag includes the code you need to copy/paste into snippets.
- You should include enough of your own CSS for your snippet to be visible in addition to any libraries you're using. Or alternatively, remove any unnecessary CSS that's hiding it.
- Don't use screenshots of text. Not all users can see images and you can't search or copy/paste from an image. Note that if your error message or code is in an image, this can get your question closed, not just downvoted, because [that information needs to be in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
- When you do use images, please either:

  - Add image descriptions
  - Describe the image in the question just above or below the image (and then just delete "enter image description")

Important Note: Heretic Monkey's comment made me realize I should make it clear that we normally don't transcribe text in an image in general and **[transcribing code is not allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375127/why-would-someone-reject-this-edit/375163#375163)** at all. I transcribed the error message because it was very short and because I found your post via a Meta question asking for help.

So don't suggest any edits where you convert images to text either, they will get rejected in review.

Comment: DO NOT expect that anyone will do that for you ever again. BSMP went way above and beyond with this.

Answer (score 7):

The main thing you need to learn here is to stop posting images of text and code. Post them as text instead or in this case you could have actually posted your non-working Stack Snippet.

Once we've got that out of the way, you're trying to add the libraries as relative paths. js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js That will only work if the library is hosted on Stack Overflow with that path. If you look at your image there's a jQuery button on the left hand side that will allow you to choose the version  of jQuery you want to include. Now that doesn't offer you 3.4.1, but perhaps

- 3.3.1 is OK
- if you do select 3.3.1 you could see how to edit it to 3.4.1 if you needed to.

At any rate, if you press that button, you get...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So this include is getting jQuery from cdnjs.cloudflare.com, so you need to do something similar with the libraries you want to use. Either find them using the buttons on the left hand side of stack snippets or you'll have to do your own searching for where they are hosted.

Finally, your reputation on Meta Stack Exchange declined because [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369674/how-to-subscribe-to-a-tag) that you abandoned was deleted. It has nothing to do with the question you're asking now. You had a couple of upvotes amongst the many downvotes, but it didn't seem you wanted to come back to salvage it, so we deleted it.